# Context-root on JBOSS EAP-7

Tags: java, virtualhost, contextroot, jboss-eap-7

We are using JBOSS EAP-7 for deploying our legacy applications. We were able to create a virtual host and re able to access the application. We wanted to have our context mentioned in jboss-web.xml file applicable.

Right now we can access the application by giving http://app.test.com but we would like to have the access as http://app.test.com/AB. So basically the context mentioned in jboss-web file (i.e. AB) is not being read.

Our jboss-web.xml file with the below code

```
 <context-root>/AB</context-root>
 <virtual-host>app.test.com</virtual-host>
```

We created the virtual host from the administrative console, as a result the entry created in standalone.xml file is as below

```
<host name="app.test.com" default-web-module="myApp.war" alias="app.test.com"/>
```

Please let us know if we missed anything or wrong on our understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have context defined in jboss-web.xml file ? As you mentioned your applications is accessible over http://app.test.com , i.e application is deployed with root context(/). If application conext is defined in jboss-web.xml then that application will be accessible over that context only.

Comment: Sorry for late reply here. Yes we have the context file as mentioned above. Not sure why its taking root context(/) instead of AB. I got busy with some other work so for now this is on hold.